# Icons not loading in admin

Tags: craft3, craft-pro

In some instances of my websites the icons don't load properly.  Everything else in the website works, but the icons don't load.  The other websites on the same server with the same php.ini file don't have this issue, just this one website.

[image: no icons]

Comment: Have you checked your network requests in the dev tools of your fav. browser? Can you see any failing requests for images?

Comment: Any updates on how you resolved this issue?

Answer (score 2):

I've had that happen before and it was just a matter of refreshing the page a few times to clear it up. If that doesn't work try clearing the control panel resources cache (or just deleting the `cpresources` folder from your webroot).

Answer (score 2):

This can sometimes be caused by your site URL being defined with http, and accessing it via https (same-origin policy? I can't remember).

Try ensuring that your access method is the same as your config.